# consistency with Element attributes in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input name='x' id='y' list='z'>
```

In JavaScript, you can do

```
var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
input.id = 'x'; //this works
input.name = 'y'; //this also works
input.list = 'z'; //this does not work
```

My question is simply: What is the magic going on here? Why do .id and .name work, but .list doesn't (needs to be set with setAttribute) Are there any common patterns or is the only way to program in Javascript to (a) know everything or (b) trial and error?

Is there a way to know (other than knowing everything) that the way to set the list attribute on an input element is using `setAttribute("list", "z");` ? And what is the magic that the setAttribute call is doing that input.list isn't?

Comment: AFAIK, `input.list` doesn't exist. Better to use `setAttribute` always. You can know the methods by doing `console.log(input)` in any browser's developer tools.

Comment: _" in Javascript to (a) know everything"_ - No, but you have to know the properties of the object you're going to work with. And that concept is not exclusive to JavaScript.

Comment: Patterns like `input.list` and `input.id` predate the existence of `setAttribute` by many years.  They probably wouldn't exist if were inventing HTML from scratch today; inconsistencies like this are caused more by historical accident than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that properties like `id` and `name` date back to a much older version of the **Document Object Model (DOM)** - back to the *DOM Level 0* (or *"Legacy DOM"*) of the mid-1990s. These DOM properties exactly correspond with their namesake attributes in the HTML Markup.

By contrast, the `list` attribute which attaches the pre-defined contents of a `<datalist>` element to an `<input>` element is much more recent. It started to arrive in most browsers around 2018-19.

*(And even now, **CanIUse** suggests [it's not ready yet in Firefox...](https://caniuse.com/?search=datalist) although my own experiments in **Firefox 83** reveal that it is.)*

So, the most robust approach will be to use:

```js
const myInput = document.createElement('input');

myInput.setAttribute('id', 'x');
myInput.setAttribute('name', 'y');
myInput.setAttribute('list', 'z');

console.log(myInput.getAttribute('id'));
console.log(myInput.getAttribute('name'));
console.log(myInput.getAttribute('list'));
```

Comment: I liked the way you explained this as an artifact of JavaScript's development over time. @DanielBeck also referred to this. Using setAttribute ubiquitously does seem like a good solution to the problems/questions I come across in this regard. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because the `list` attribute of an [`HTMLInputElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#htmlinputelement) is defined to be read-only

> ```
> interface HTMLInputElement : HTMLElement {
>   [HTMLConstructor] constructor();
>
>   ...
>   readonly attribute HTMLElement? list;   
>   ...
>   
> }
> ```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#htmlinputelement

Comment: This is a good point. But (perhaps inconsistently?) you can _still_ set the `list` attribute using the `.setAttribute()` method. Setting the attribute will initialise the `list` property with a value.

Comment: @Rounin `.setAttribute()` is a method of `Element`. There's no reason why it would have to know anything about limitations of derived DOM elements. That the `.list` attribute is then updated I find only logical (imho).

Comment: I think I was wrong about _"Setting the attribute will initialise the list property with a value."_ It looks like, even when I set the `list` attribute, the `list` property remains `null`.

Comment: Interesting to know about `list` being read-only. Between your and Rounin's answers, it has really dawned on me that what I think I know about Javascript is based largely in when I first started diving into it in the mid-90s, and that while still backward compatible, JavaScript today has matured while I haven't been paying attention. Just realizing this is/will be very useful for me. Thank you!